# How to customise the "Snooze Until" times in Google Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Is it possible to customise (add, delete, change) the "Snooze until..." times in Google Inbox?

[image: "Snooze until..." menu]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the definitions for *Morning*, *Afternoon*, and *Evening*.

Open the "hamburger" menu and scroll all the way to the bottom. Click "Settings".

[image: lower portion of menu]

Choose the "Snooze" tab.

[image: "Snooze" tab before changes]

Change the times to what you want.

[image: "Snooze" tab after changes]

Unfortunately, you can't change "Later today", "Tomorrow", or "Next week", except insofar as "Later today" is whatever time (*Morning*, *Afternoon*, *Evening*) is coming up next, "Tomorrow" is your *Morning* time the next day, and "Next week" is the *Morning* time a week from now.

If that's a feature that you think Inbox needs, you should use the "Feedback" tool to let Google know.